# Cannot switch sender email when using ReplyAll via Outlook in Python Win32

Tags: outlook, pywin32, win32com

I have multiple account associated to my outlook, i am trying to set the From field to this one specific email i own. Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem I should be able to accomplish this by changing the SendUsingAccount property, however, i am running into ERROR:root:(-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1). Does anyone know why?

```
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
selection = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
count = selection.Count + 1
for i in range(1, count):
    message = selection.Item(i)
    reply = message.ReplyAll()
    newBody = "test"
    for myEmailAddress in outlook.Session.Accounts:
       if "@test.com" in str(myEmailAddress):
           From = myEmailAddress
           break
           print(From.DisplayName) #prints the email i want fine
    reply.SendUsingAccount = From.DisplayName #this line is giving me the error. If I remove it , the email popups fine, but the From address is defaulting to one i dont want to use
    reply.HTMLBody = newBody + reply.HTMLBody
    reply.Display(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Session.Accounts` collection returns `Account` objects, not strings. And `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property takes an `Account` object, not a string.

Replace the line

```
if "@test.com" in str(myEmailAddress):
```

with

```
if "@test.com" in str(myEmailAddress.SmtpAddress):
```

and

```
Reply.SendUsingAccount = From.DisplayName
```

with

```
Reply.SendUsingAccount = From
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! but i am a bit confused... how is my other code with mail = outlook.CreateItem(0) then same ... grab account..  self.mail.SendUsingAccount = From.DisplayName, self.mail.Send() working then? It is sending out the emails fine with my email set in SendUsingAccount.

Comment: Hard to say... Are you sure you are not just eating the exceptions?